# Let HTML5 Notification disappear after a delay?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-notifications

I want to use HTML5 notifications which work great.

The problem is that they never disappear.

**How can I set a delay after which the HTML5 notification disappear?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just call the `.close()` method:

```
var n = new Notification("Hello");
setTimeout(n.close.bind(n), 2000);
```

See [here on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notification/close) for details.

Comment: @confile - So that `n.close()` is called with the appropriate `this` value.

Comment: I don't get it. Why not just do ``n.close()``?

Comment: @confile - You have to pass a reference to the method.  If you just pass `n.close`, it will not call it properly.  The value of `n` will be lost when the close method is called.  If you pass `n.close()`, then it will be executed IMMEDIATELY, not later when the `setTimeout()` fires.  The parens `()` mean to execute the function NOW.  Without the parens is a function reference that `setTimeout()` can call later (which is what is wanted here).

Comment: @confile - You could also use `setTimeout(function() { n.close(); }, 2000);`, but the version I show is more compact.

Answer (score 1):

The notification should have a built in close button, no?

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" onclick="return show()">Notify me!</a>
```

**JS**

```
<script>
        var Notification = window.Notification || window.mozNotification || window.webkitNotification;

        Notification.requestPermission(function (permission) {
            // console.log(permission);
        });

        function show() {
            var instance = new Notification(
                "Hey", {
                    body: "this is a message"
                }
            );

            instance.onclick = function () {
                // Something to do
            };
            instance.onerror = function () {
                // Something to do
            };
            instance.onshow = function () {
                // Something to do
            };
            instance.onclose = function () {
                // Something to do
            };

            return false;
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: I thought the point of the OP's question was that they want it displayed only for a certain amount of time and don't want the user to have to dismiss it so I'm not sure how this code solves what they were asking for.